# Javascript google spreadsheets: how do I find the max value within a group

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In google spreadsheets I have a column with repeated rows of years and a column of values. I want to write a script that finds the maximum value for each year. I have found the maximum value of all years with the script below but am having great difficulty finding a maximum for each year and logging it into a new column.

```
function findmax(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var column = 9; 
var colArray = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math, colArray)
Logger.log(maxi)
```

Any idea?

Comment: A sheet formula to achieve this would be something like =query(A1:B30,"select A, max(B) group by A ")  where the dates are in column A and the values in col B.  (+for Konstant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function maxGroupBy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var yearCol = 1; // <-assumption that the two column are not adjacent.
  var column = 9;

  var yearArray = sheet.getRange(1, yearCol, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var colArray = sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  var group = {};
  for (var i = 0; i< yearArray.length; i++) {
    group[yearArray[i]] = Math.max((group[yearArray[i]] || colArray[i]), colArray[i]);
  }
  for (key in group) {
    Logger.log(key + "::" + group[key]);  
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How would I add a third filter. say for example for each  year there are multiple countries? So I want the maximum within a specific year and country

Comment: The key of the `group` could be a combination of two or more columns (maybe separated by a delimiter). So instead of `yearArray[i]` as the key, you could use `yearArray[i] + "|" + countryArray[i]`.

Comment: perfect that's really useful! I now have the maxima for each year*country. I would now like to divide each value by the maximum for that year and country. So if January in australia is 400 then I would like  a new column with value=400/maximum in australia in 2011. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Hmm... So you would need to do another parse on the `colArray` and do the required calculations.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help so far. I am new to javascript so not entirely sure how to do that. I have tried the following which creates a new column. But that only returns the maximum values regardless of year and country.                                          var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()  ;
for(n=1;n<lastRow;++n){;
var adddatas = sheet.getRange("K2:K"+lastRow);
    adddatas.setValue(group[key]);

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) { sheet.getRange(i + 1, outputColumnNumber).setValue(colArray[i]/group[yearArray[i] + "|" + countryArray[i]]); }` This is not the best solution but it will give you an idea (PS: I have not tested this).

Comment: once again I really appreciate your comments. I've been at this all day and still can't find a solution. I tried pasting the script but I get a error message saying service error: spreadsheets. Do you know by any chance if there is something I should tweak. Once again thanks for all your help